# Cantus de beata virgine quae de ea in sabbatis agitur officium in conventu

Tags: medieval-latin

This is a rubric for the hymn Ave maris stella from a French 13th century source.  Someone helped me and gave me:  'A song for the Blessed Virgin when her office is celebrated on Saturdays in the monastery.'  I'm looking for a literal translation.  Is this close?  Thank you.

Comment: I'm having a really hard time parsing this. Is this the whole sentence?

Comment: *De beata Maria virgine in sabbatis officium* (Office of the Blessed Virgin Mary on Saturday) is a popular devotional office for Saturday liturgies. I have noticed that *Sabbata*, the plural of *Sabbatum* is often used in a singular sense, almost as if it were a *plurale tantum*, so it could be interpreted as singular "Saturday" as well as plural "Saturdays", not that that makes much difference in meaning.

Comment: Ya, I checked again.  I copied it correctly.  It may be one of those cases that mixes in local dialects, I don't know.

Comment: @R.B.Jawad Do you have an image or link you can post? I'm really skeptical of the "quae." I could easily see someone who didn't know paleography misinterpreting an abbreviation, e.g. it could be "quando" (as the translation you posted seems to assume), which would make a lot more sense.

Comment: I tried to find the original source online, but couldn't.  It's apparently from Roma, Santa Sabina, Archivum Generale Ordinis Predicatorum s. n., in a manuscript Correctorium des Humbert von Romans ("le gros livre"), ca. 1255.  Here is an image from Stäblein's book: https://pasteboard.co/J5t50Xu.png

Comment: Has anyone heard of an idiom where *quae de ea* equals *de qua*? I'd really like to change *quae de ea* to *de qua* or *cum de ea* (which is what I think R.B.Jawad's translator did), but I cannot justify it.

Comment: Maybe the quae is just a dangling nominative. Those are common enough in all periods.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to https://cantus.uwaterloo.ca/chant/675638, the correct reading of this line in a Dominican hymnary is indeed *Cantus de beata virgine **quando** in sabbatis de ea agitur officium in conventu*, which indeed translates as **"A hymn¹ of² the Virgin Mary when her office is celebrated on Saturdays in the convent³"** [Footnotes: ¹ or "song" or "chant", but "hymn" would be the usual liturgical term; ² or "about"; ³ or "monastery", but this manuscript was for the use of Dominican nuns, so "convent" would be the more usual word].

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response.

Answer (score 0):

A hymn *about* the Blessed Virgin... The rest is certainly correct, although the *quae* is indeed odd.

Comment: Do you have an alternative translation that you think makes more sense, or explains why you think _quae_ is odd? I think it would help improve your answer to include that.

Comment: One would expect the pronoun q... to refer to cantus, which however is masculine. (qui). It's not really clear to me how quae could be explained (e.g. it doesn't make sense for it to refer to virgo).